# Netsuite: Server-side code not firing for csv uploads?

Tags: netsuite

I created a script and deployed it to automatically populate web store fields when new inventory items are created in our system.

The code works when a new item is created through the interface, but does not when a new item is uploaded via csv.

This is the code:

```
function userEventAfterSubmit(type) {
if (type == 'create') {
    var newItem = nlapiLoadRecord('inventoryitem', nlapiGetNewRecord().getId());
    var storeDisplayImage = nlapiGetFieldValue('storedisplayimage');
    if (storeDisplayImage == '' || storeDisplayImage == null)
        newItem.setFieldValue('storedisplayimage', 620128);
    var storeDisplayThumbnail = nlapiGetFieldValue('storedisplaythumbnail');
    if (storeDisplayThumbnail == '' || storeDisplayThumbnail == null)
        newItem.setFieldValue('storedisplaythumbnail', 620127);
    var urlComponent = nlapiGetFieldValue('urlcomponent');
    if (urlComponent == '' || urlComponent == null)
        newItem.setFieldValue('urlcomponent', nlapiGetFieldValue('storedisplayname'));
    var pageTitle = nlapiGetFieldValue('pagetitle');
    if (pageTitle == '' || pageTitle == null)
        newItem.setFieldValue('pagetitle', nlapiGetFieldValue('storedisplayname'));
    var storeDescription = nlapiGetFieldValue('storedescription');
    if (storeDescription == '' || storeDescription == null)
        newItem.setFieldValue('storedescription', nlapiGetFieldValue('salesdescription'));
    var storeDetailedDescription = nlapiGetFieldValue('storedetaileddescription');
    if (storeDetailedDescription == '' || storeDetailedDescription == null)
        newItem.setFieldValue('storedetaileddescription', nlapiGetFieldValue('salesdescription'));
    var metaTagHtml = nlapiGetFieldValue('metataghtml');
    if (metaTagHtml == '' || metaTagHtml == null)
        newItem.setFieldValue('metataghtml', '<meta name="description" content="' + nlapiGetFieldValue('salesdescription') + '">');
    nlapiSubmitRecord(newItem);
}
```

}

And then this function is called as the "After Submit Function". Am I not calling in this in the right place for it to run for csv uploads?

This is my script deployment:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Goto "Setup > Import/Export > CSV Import preferences"
2. Make sure " RUN SERVER SUITESCRIPT AND TRIGGER WORKFLOWS" is checked.

Comment: It was not checked, I have now checked it (talk about random things you have to know). Once our ops team arrives and we test it out I will accept the answer and up-vote. Thanks!

Comment: So we have this checked now, and the script still doesn't run when csv files are uploaded.

Comment: can you confirm your deployment options are correct - like event type is not selected, roles/employees are correct and execute as role is correct?

Comment: I edited my original post with a pic of the script deployment

Comment: Yeah, it is here in the deployment! Please check All roles for now or select the specific employee in the employee column in the context of whom the csv upload is being done